# Select distinct values of two columns as single

Tags: mysql, select

For starters: yes, I've seen there are lots of questions on combining two/multiple columns - but so far I neither found *the* answer to my question nor something to get me started trying further (which I did).

---

**I have:** a table consisting of two `INT` fields.
**I want:** a single column holding the distinct values of both fields.

Examle table:

```
| a | b |
|---|---|
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 5 | 7 |
```

My desired result would in that case be:

```
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 7 |
```

Can this be done with a single query? What would that look like?

// EDIT: some side info (which I think is irrelevant, however, I don't want to hide it):
**b is always greater than a**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT a AS result
FROM tableX

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT b 
FROM tableX ;
```

Comment: Thanks. That was fast. Does this mean there is no solution with only a single `SELECT`? It's only a single query, yes. I should've written `SELECT` in my question, though. :)

Comment: I don't see why one would want this weird requirement (a single `SELECT` keyword in the query). But no, I don't think that is possible.

Comment: `UNION DISTINCT` gives an incorrect result. Just `UNION` seems correct. Any idea on this?

Comment: `UNION` and `UNION DISTINCT` should give you the same exact result. What result did you get?

Comment: `1 1 1 2 3 5` - instead of `1 2 3 5 7`.

Comment: With `UNION DISTINCT`? No way.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/lftL7v2.png **VS** https://i.imgur.com/SC74SnW.png

Comment: Are you sure this is not a result from a previous query? Try it again and confirm please. This should not happen. And which version of MySQL do you use?

Comment: Yep. I can do this as often (wrong) as I want. :) I'm using 10.1.10-MariaDB, which in fact **is** not MySQL, but we are talking about plain MySQL stuff here, right?

Comment: Then this is a bug in MariaDB 10.1.10 (it should not happen in MySQL, nor in Maria). I suggest you post a bug request to MariaDB. Or download the latest version, they may have fixed it already.

Comment: @tfrommen: Just to confirm that this should work in MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8971ab/1